# Goodnight or Have a nice day?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

Last night, my friend and I have to work until 3 in the morning. We did not sleep at all.

When we decided to go to sleep, he said, “Have a nice day”. In my opinion, he should have said “goodnight” even though it was past 3 AM because we did not sleep at all.

So what should one say in this context?

Comment: I think your friend's "Have a nice day" statement was meant to be sarcastic. unless there's so much fervor (doing labour) kidding.

Answer (score 4):

In this situation, "Have a nice day" could mean:

> Have a nice day [tomorrow, that is, when you wake up later].

Or, it could have been intended to be somewhat humorous:

> Have a nice day – whatever few minutes are left of it.

There is nothing wrong with what your friend said. Moreover, "Goodnight" could have been a fitting reply, given the odd time of the dialog.

There is no one thing that "should" be said. There are several ways to wish someone well when departing.

Answer (score 0):

I think a very polite form will be:

> I'm working on it! You too!

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Enrique. I don't understand how this answers the OP's question. could you possibly explain in a little more detail?

Comment: You think?  Could you please explain why you think this?

Answer (score -1):

How about, "[Have a nice/good/great sleep!](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225403/have-a-great-sleep)"

Basically, 3am (Devil's Hour) is night. So, "Goodnight!" is good!